# Concrete5 site not working in IE with Document mode:Quirks

Tags: php, content-management-system, concrete5

I have developed one site in Concrete 5 which runs well in every browser even in every IE browsers also but when i change ie document mode to **Quirks**  the site is totally messed up

Can you suggest me that where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you use the IE in quirks mode it works like an IE5 and so you only have the IE5 CSS. Thats why the site is diplayed 'different'.

Have a look at
[Force IE9 into Quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123326/force-ie9-into-quirks-mode)
for more information about IE and quirks mode.