# css3 not working inside an iframe of Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe, css

None of the CSS3 properties like `border-radius` and `box-shadow` are working inside an `<iframe>` in IE, though they work perfectly fine in other browsers, and even in IE when not placed in an `<iframe>`.

Has anyone found any problems like this and ever fixed them?

Please help!

```
<style type='text/css'>

.seath {
    background-color: #7eaf47;
margin:16px 0px 16px 0px;
padding:16px 16px 16px 16px;
    position: relative;
width:320px;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;

    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #444444; /*firefox 3.6 and earlier*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #444444; /*safari*/
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #444444;

}
</style>

<div class='seath'>
...
</div>
```

Comment: If you are using the iframe to display another webpage, how does the page look when you view the page separately?

Comment: Are both your parent document and the iframe document in [standards mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode)?

Comment: @anothershrubery: I'm using the iframe in the sidebar  for log-in/signUp purpose only

Comment: @Dipesh: do you see the same behaviour in the final version of IE 9? If the issue only occurs in the beta, I don’t think it’s worth changing your code (as “beta” means “not finished”).

Comment: @Paul D.Waite: I haven't tested that on the final version yet, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Start your `iframe` html document this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
(...)
```

This should force the browser to render in standards mode.