# IFRAME in IE cannot display transparency

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, iframe

I have a website with transparencies which work in IE9: `http://199.193.248.80/transparency.html`

But if I iframe that page, the transparencies stop working in IE: `http://199.193.248.80/iframe.html`

How can it be fixed? I've tried every trick I could find on google including `allowtransparency="true" frameborder=0` Nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely rewritten answer:

You are in Quirks Mode.

IE renders iframes as separate document nodes, doctype is not inherited, and quirks is the default. You need to alter the DOCTYPE of the HTML document in the iframe to instruct the browser to run in standards mode.  Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode).  I think it will help you.

Comment: No, compare the difference between http://199.193.248.80/transparency.html and http://199.193.248.80/iframe.html in IE9, there is no transparency at all. It is like IE is using compatibility mode

Comment: Its actually using Quirks mode.

Comment: How can Quirks Mode be turned off?

Comment: In IE 9 iframe html doc's now inherit the viewing mode of their parent, so I think you need to alter the DOCTYPE of iframe.html to instruct the browser to run in standards mode.  Take a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode).  I think it will help you.

Comment: Thanks. Want to delete this answer and repost with that link so I can accept and upvote?

Comment: I just edited my original answer.  Sorry for the poor initial answer.  Head was too far down in the weeds.