# Image Not Being Displayed Atalasoft/Telerik IE8/IE9 issue

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8, telerik, internet-explorer-9

I have a Telerik radGrid that when a gridrow is clicked, it will expand and display an image that uses Atalasoft DotImage (version  9.0.3.45452) ImageViewer to display the image.

Everything worked with IE8. Any broswer IE9+, it seems to not show the image. The image appears in other areas of the application (and works), but it is not attached to any Telerik controls.

I have scouring the internet to see what was changed between IE8 & IE9, but I have not found anything that would help me out.

The image will show in the Telerik grid using IE8 & in developer tools, if I use quirks mode.

Could someone point me in the right direction between the two browsers and their rendering of these controls in a high-level sense?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it has to deal with iframes, parent doctypes, and IE9. I have found a reference
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode)