# is it possible to define internet explorer version for iframe?

Tags: internet-explorer, iframe

We have some web applications which are compatible in internet explorer version 9 and not in 10. I'm creating another web application which is compatible only in  ie 10 version and it contains iframe and need to give source as first application which compatible only in 9 version.
Is it possible for iframe to open in internet explorer version 9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has been asked before (many times). Here's [one answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode/5624373#5624373). Please search for more results with keywords `[internet-explorer]iframe compatibility`.

Comment: @Teemu so I need to add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> in first application which is compatible in ie9. Is there any way to make it possible with out making any changes in first application?