# IE9 - Quirks Mode and <jsp:include>

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer, iframe

after trying every doctype and meta-tag recommended, I couldn't figure out how to disable quirks mode on IE9.

The project has a main jsp and renders dynamically inside of it using .

When I an **onkeypress** event is fired I get a "HTML1113: Document mode restart from Quirks to IE9 Standards".

I tried using this on every jps, but no luck:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/> 
</head>
...
```

Maybe the jsp:include implementation uses iframe, in which case I'll never get rid of the quirks mode, or that is what understand about the demonstration in this post [Will an iframe render in quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717932/will-an-iframe-render-in-quirks-mode)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to pass this on but the main/containing page is the only one that can fully determine both the browser mode and the document mode, quirks mode is IE7.  So if jsp:include is indeed contained (which it looks like) then the only solution is to alter the main/containing page.

Phil

Comment: Unless you are using a servlet of some kind. But that is JSF not JSP

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't get it. I just tried to emule IE7, but not luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet that the page being included has another `<html>` block, i.e. it's a full page not just an html snippet. Obviously having 2 or 3 `<html>` blocks is a *quirk*.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. The only mistake that I did was I included the **doctype** and **meta tag** in both parent and child jsps which was causing the issue. Please remove them in child jsps, which was already included in parent jsp and keep it only in parent always which will solve this issue.